# Offline Version of Single Page Applications

Tags: javascript, java, single-page-application

What are the techniques and the tools, libraries and frameworks necessary to make a SPA in java (and javascript)?

Consider an application served by a server A. This server might go offline.

What I need is a partially functional, read-only version of that application on a second server B, but fully navigable.

Server B can only serve static files: html, css, js, images.

Server A has access to server B and can push data to it as required and on a regular basis.

My second requirement is to suffer as less as possible from vendor lock-in, so I should be using as little frameworks as possible.

The third requirement is: there should be no necessity of any tool on the client's side, in the browser.

Please list the possible techniques, and where applicable, also at least one tool/framework/library, so I can search for alternatives to that one if, for whatever reason, it doesn't fit my bill.

Comment: I'm an experienced programmer (10 years+), so please phrase your answers accordingly. I need some key words in terms of tooling, because I've never written an SPA, and my java is rusty, so I don't know the ecosystem.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, the Java app would be able to render any page at the first visit anyway - because sharing bookmarks should also work from the end user's perspective. So I imagine something like: server A generates all required files when an article is changed in the database, and pushes them as a static view of that article to server B, without any sign of a SPA.

Answer (score 2):

**If you accept any client-side code:**

Yes, the best answer are service workers.

You can read about various caching techniques [on Jake's site](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/)

Easiest plugin to make your website accessible offline is https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache.

Service workers are framework-agnostic, you can use them with all frameworks or without one in JavaScript.

You will need typical backend (Java/PHP?) or even static html files, and JavaScript client-side code.

**If you don't accept any client-side code and accept 3rd parties**:

The only solution is to have some kind of proxy like CloudFlare - your DNS will point to CloudFlare, and they you set up what will happen.

**If you don't accept any cliend-side code and don't accept 3rd parties**:
If you want your solution exactly as you've described, you should use some kind of load balancer like HAProxy (http://www.haproxy.org/), which will route your traffic to failover server. You can read about this here: http://blog.haproxy.com/2013/12/23/failover-and-worst-case-management-with-haproxy/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please read my refined question as it is now.

Comment: sw-precache seems to be a node module, my question is tagged java and the question also says java, that is: under normal circumstances, the REST replies are returned by java on server A. Server B does not have any server-side technology on it. Depending on cloudflare or any other service is like the mother of all vendor lock-in and not an option.

If I understand your answer wrongly please let me know. Let's work together to find a good solution.

Comment: `sw-precache` only uses node for development, you can use it with any server technology. You can write service worker by yourself as well. However, this option would require someone to visit your page at least once. 

Edited my answer.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, the rendered out page is built on the client's browser (as it normally would) and sent to the server A as a stand-alone page (and A can upload the files to B) on each change of the window location. `sw-precache` is run by each client's browser. Or I can arrange for a dedicated user to do that on server A, in a headless browser. Are these assumptions right?

Comment: Not exactly. In client-side option you don't need 'Server B'. 
When user enters your site, the service worker can tell the browser to cache specific resources (static html, js, css). Then, when the user will enter your site once again, and your site will be down, service worker can tell the browser to use cached static page instead. You can also update this files (sw-precache uses control sum to verify if it has changed), but the user obviously needs to enter the page when the new assets will be accessible.

Comment: I don't need to cache the resulting html after following a link in the client's browser. I need to have it on server B for all other possible users, in case server A goes offline unexpectedly.

Comment: Then use the load balancer, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, the Java app would be able to render any page at the first visit anyway - because sharing bookmarks should also work from the end user's perspective. So I imagined more something like: server A generated all required files when an article is changed in the database, and pushes them as a static view of that article to server B, without any sign of a SPA.